# What is $\mathbb{Q}_1$, the "field of $1$-adic numbers"?

Tags: p-adic-numbers, field-with-one-element

(Disclaimer: I'm totally ignorant about $\mathbb{F}_1$ theory)

There are now (several) working definitions of the "field with one element" $\mathbb{F}_1$ (not literally a field, of course), and certain mathematical objects "over $\mathbb{F}_1$" are recognized. For example, $\mathbb{F}_1$-vector spaces are pointed sets, $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_1)$ is the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ on $n$ elements (or was it $n-1$? $n+1$?). As far as I remember there's even a notion of "algebraic variety over $\mathbb{F}_1$": they are related to toric varieties.

So, my question:

> Say $\mathbb{F}_p$ is to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as $\mathbb{F}_1$ is to some object that we call $\mathbb{Q}_1$. How can $\mathbb{Q}_1$ be described explicitely in terms of more conventional mathematical objects?

The same question could be asked for $\mathbb{Z}_1$, $\mathbb{C}_1$, $\Omega_1$.

Comment: Shouldn't the standard analogies suggest $\mathbb{Q}_1=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}_1=[-1,1]$ and $\Omega_1=\mathbb{C}_1=\mathbb{C}$? Though I did also hear someone mentions that $\mathbb{Z}_1$ should be the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Uri Bader: you may want to post your comment as an answer, together with the heuristics that suggest your equalities.

Comment: What's the implied relation between ${\bf F}_p$ and ${\bf Q}_p$? One has characteristic $p$, the other characteristic zero.

Comment: Dear Qfwfq, I am as interested as you are in reading good answers to your question. I will learn nothing new (and probably so will you) from giving my own lame answer. Maybe I shouldn't have made my comment, but I couldn't hold my typing finger...

Comment: @GerryMyerson Relations between $\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ are clearer - former is the residue field of the latter, and the latter is the ring of Witt vectors of the former. $\mathbb Q_p$ is then the field of fractions of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Would be cool if the answer satisfies an analogue of the Fontaine-Winterberger galois group isomorphism :P

Comment: (btw, I bet somebody will eventually come up with a definition of "$\mathbb{Q}_1$ adic/rigid analytic space" or of a  "perfectoid algebra for characteristic $1$", but first things first.... :D )

Comment: @UriBader I think there are several different "mythical fields", the "field with one element" being different from the "residue field of $\mathbb{R}$". It is the latter whose corresponding "adic field" should be $\mathbb{R}$ as you suggest. The former ought to be different. (Although the residue field of $\mathbb{R}$ has "one element", it has "two nonzero elements", viz. "positive" and "negative".)

Comment: For what it's worth, in 2003, I attended a lecture by Soulé called something like "variétés sur le corps à un élément", and at the end, someone asked essentially your question (in the form "what would the Witt ring of $\mathbb{F}_1$ be?"). Sadly, Soulé just answered that he didn't know and that he didn't understand the point of the question.

Comment: Whatever $\mathbb Q_1$ is, since reductive groups over $\mathbb F_1$ are spherical Weyl groups, reductive groups over $\mathbb Q_1$ must be affine Weyl groups.

Answer (score 9):

Completions of a field are associated to places of that field. So for instance, $\mathbb Q(i)$ has two different completions of residue characteristic $5$. But $\mathbb F_1$ is not supposed to be a place of $\mathbb Q$. It is supposed to be the base field of $\mathbb Q$, which is different.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with a "base field"?

Comment: @Wojowu a lot of $\mathbb F_1$-theory is based on the analogy with $\mathbb F_q[t]$, where $\mathbb F_q$ is the base field and every other field in sight lies over it. $\mathbb F_1$ should be the same $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q, \mathbb F_p$, and so on should be extensions of it.

Comment: Let me ask a more specific question then: is it possible to make sense out of the ring of Witt vectors over $\mathbb F_1$?

Comment: @Wojowu I don't have a guess of what the Witt ring is but I like to think of the tropical integers $\mathbb{N}, max, +$ as $\mathbb{F}_1[t]$ but I haven't managed to do anything with that.

Comment: One can also say that there is a candidate of residue field $\mathbb{F}_{\infty}$ at the place at infinity by Durov, which is not $\mathbb F_1$, since it should have addition (in this case, idempotent addition).

Answer (score 2):

In Borger's model of $\mathbb{F}_1$ geometry at least, the more specific question "what is the ring of Witt vectors of $\mathbb{F}_1$" proposed by Wojowu is essentially meaningless.

Indeed, according to Borger's picture, an $\mathbb{F}_1$-algebra should be the same as a $\lambda$-ring, and the "restriction of scalar from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{F}_1$" should be the Witt vectors functor from rings to $\lambda$-rings (note that the Witt vectors always have a natural $\lambda$-ring structure since $\lambda$-rings can be seen as coalgebras for a suitable comonad structure on the Witt vectors functor). If we think of Witt vectors in this way as restriction of scalars, it really only makes sense for classical rings over $\mathbb{Z}$, not for $\mathbb{F}_1$-algebras.